# Editing View of Sharepoint Groups in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: groups, view

How could I edit a View of user Sharepoint Groups in Sharepoint 2013 ? I have got 2 Views, but I don't know how to edit tchem to show only for two columns. Name and Surname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue and solved it by following steps .

1. go to the parent site (root site) and navigate to your SharePoint group from settings .
2. Once you Inside the group click on settings and then List settings
3. Inside List setting its you can change the view and add or remove columns to show/hide.

[image]

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Yes now it work, but how could I edit a view to specific group?

Comment: sorry but editing view for specific group is not possible I guess. But we can always create a new view and show it to specific group from view change dropdown.

Comment: For a custom view we can create new view and give its direct link to user to show your custom view by default to user. All we have to do is to go inside the group then change the view and copy the url. Give this link to the user and your custom view will be shown to user by default. Hope this solves your issue

Comment: Yes great :) Its great solution :)

Comment: Please mark this as answer so it can help others also

Comment: Here You Are :)